# itemize without line feed

Tags: spacing, lists, itemize

When I write a document with `\usepackage[french]{babel}` my `\begin{itemize} \end{itemize}` list begin with '-' before each item and no extra line feed before each item. But when I don't use this package (when I want to write an english document), my lists are transformed with a bullet before each item AND an extra line feed between each item (as if a new line was inserted). I can deactivate the bullets with `\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{}` but how to suppress the extra line feed ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to use the customization options provided by the `enumitem` package :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{enumitem}
% \setlist{noitemsep} % Uncomment this if you want it as a global setting

\begin{document}

Default spacing :
\begin{itemize}
\item item 1
\item item 2
\end{itemize}

Suppressing the space by hand :
\begin{itemize}
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
\item item 1
\item item 2
\end{itemize}

Using enumitem :
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
\item item 1
\item item 2
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 4):

With [the `enumitem` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem), you can

1. Globaly adjust it via:

   ```
        \setlist[itemize]{itemsep=-4pt}
   ```

   which yields the first list below.
2. Alternatively you can also specify it on a per list basis:

   ```
        \begin{itemize}[itemsep=0pt]
   ```

   which produces the second list above.
3. You can define you own list via `\newlist` which behaves the way you desire which produces the third list shown below.

   [image]

### Notes:

- I have used different values of `itemsep` just so that in the image you can see that there are three different lists.  But either of the three methods can produce the spacing you desire, you just need to decide which use model is more appropriate.

---

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[french]{babel} 

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{itemsep=-2pt}

\newlist{MyItemize}{itemize}{3}
\setlist[MyItemize]{itemsep=-4pt}

\begin{document}

Default ajusted spacing:
\begin{itemize}
\item item 1
\item item 2
\end{itemize}

Adjusting the space on a per use basis:
\begin{itemize}[itemsep=0pt]
\item item 1
\item item 2
\end{itemize}

Use a custom list type:
\begin{itemize}[itemsep=-4pt]
\item item 1
\item item 2
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution is to use `compactitem` (loading the`paralist` package)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist}
\begin{document}

\begin{compactitem}
\item a
\item b
\end{compactitem}


\end{document}
```