# Write a line without listing inside a list

Tags: lists, itemize

How can I write a line without listing inside a list like below

[image]

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131637/no-indentation-for-non-item-within-itemize help?

Comment: @egreg I noticed the post 'itemize without line feed' (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84175/itemize-without-line-feed?rq=1). But I don't  want indentation.

Comment: That one is a different problem.